# PL SQL line by line comparison with existing data and accept/ignore values

Tags: plsql, procedure

I have a line to be compared with existing data in `PL SQL`. Every entered data is getting compared with existing data through a procedure.  (`PL/SQL`)
If the magnitude of the entered data is negative in comparison with existing data and all other columns are same, it should be ignored.
If similar data comes again, it should be captured in a error statement.

```
                col1    col2     col3   col4    output
existing data   abcd    xyz      ijk     100    
entered data    abcd    xyz      ijk    -100    ignored
entered data    abcd    xyz      ijk    -100    to be captured in a error
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you please share your procedure code?

Comment: @Pirate: thanks for your consideration. The procedure involves with debit/credit memos and so not to be shared. I just need the logic with the subquery to accomplish the aforementioned scenario.

Initial line received                : DM1    ----- 10 PKGS     100$
     Return submitted      : DM 2   ---- - -10 PKGS  -100$  ignored
     Line submitted          : DM 3   ---- - -10 PKGS    100$ error

Thanks!

Comment: What subquery? Sounds like you want to join two sets of data and compare values.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this :

- you have an input of four chunks of information, col1, col2, col3,
  col4
- cols 1-3 are strings
- col4 is a number (happens to be currency)

For an individual row of data you have the following logic to run against a table (call it SAMPLE_DATA)

- if cols 1-3 do not match cols 1-3 in SAMPLE_DATA = valid data
- if cols 1-3 match but col4 does not = valid data
- if cols 1-3 match and col4 matches but equal and opposite = ignored
- if cols 1-3 match and col4 matches = error

So your problem is simple  -

- count all the rows that match cols 1-4 (A)
- count the cols that match cols 1-3 and also (col4 * -1) (B)

The resulting logic is

```
IF A = 0 AND B = 0 = valid
IF A > 0 AND B = 1 = ignore
IF A > 0 AND B > 1 = error
```

That's all pretty easy to code - have I missed the point?

Comment: Thanks for your help!. I guess, you understood it in wrong manner. As explained in my question,col1      col2        col3       col4  
Initial line                    :  abcd     123      10 pkgs   100    
Return submitted1      :   abcd     123     -10 pkgs  -100    
Return submitted2      :    abcd     123     -10 pkgs  100 
In return submitted 1 - all columns data are similar to Initial line, with negative sign. this can be ignored, no error.
In return submitted2, again the same line with similar data with different magnitude. Duplicate to 1st and 2nd line. error. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not helping me to help you.  My second set of bullet points is a summary of the logic that I think you are trying to apply.  Which of them is incorrect and why?  If you can answer that question perhaps we can move forward

Comment: here you go with the revised requirement.
Scenario# 1         
Submittor |s Contract |s BU |s Prod |s Invoice |s Inv Date |s Units |s Cont Price |s Error |s Comments
A123456 |s A10001 |s 10001 |s 1001 |s 100101 |s 08/25/2016 |s 4 |s 100$ |s No Duplicate 
A123456 |s A10001 |s 10001 |s 1001 |s 100101 |s 08/25/2016 |s -4 |s 100$ |s When -ve units less than or equal to original units then no error

Comment: Line  |s Submittor |s Contract |s  BU   |s Prod |s Invoice |s Inv Date   |s Units |s Price |s Error     
Orig  |s  A123456  |s  A10001  |s 10001 |s 1001 |s 100101  |s 08/25/2016 |s   4   |s  100$ |s   
Line1 |s  A123456  |s  A10001  |s 10001 |s 1001 |s 100101  |s 08/25/2016 |s  -4   |s  100$ |s no error